# Initializing structs after declaration

Tags: c, struct, scope

I have a struct named `point` that stores variables `x` and `y`.

```
typedef struct point{
    int x, y;
}point;
```

Inside a function, I define a set of structs with type `point` for use later in the program.

`point p1,p2,p3,p4;`

I then later try to initialize the variables within an if statement that is checking for a condition. I keep getting different errors when trying to initialize the variables. What is the proper way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

```
if(check1 != 0){
    p1 = { x, y };
}else if(check2 != 0){
    p2 = { x, y };
}else if(check3 != 0){
    p3 = { x, y };
}else if(check4 != 0){
    p4 = { x, y };
}
```

Edit: The numbers as variable names were for examples' sake, and is something else in context with the rest of the program. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: You need to read a tutorial from the very first page. You cant name a variable as a number. So `point 1;` is *very* invalid,. (You try to assignate a value to the number 1!!!) Then even if you rename your point 1 `p1` the logic of your code remains spurious.

Comment: More precisely, a variable name can contain numbers but it can't start with a number. So `_1` would be a valid but horribly chosen name. We should strive to pick meaningful names that describe the purpose of the variable.

Comment: *"Getting different errors"* - What errors?

Comment: We don't have enough information about the errors or where various variables origin from. And please be aware that you don't invalidate previously given answers if you edit your question.

Comment: @Lundin You should note that starting identifiers with underscore is reserved completely for the implementation AFAIK.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Strictly speaking yes, but it's a valid variable name otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers (as variable names) cant start with a number. Most times you use a letter. As a suggestion declare the variables like that:

```
point point1, point2, point3, point4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) you can do this:

```
p1 = (struct point){ x, y };
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *initialization* is when you give a variable a value during declaration. You can only do that once. To give it a value later is known as *assignment*.

The proper way to write your code would be to use arrays and a loop, for a simple linear search algorithm. Example:

```
bool  check [N] = /* something */ ;
point point_arr [N];

for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
  if(check[i] != 0)
  {
    point_arr[i].x = x;
    point_arr[i].y = y;
    break; // break the loop and stop searching here
  }
}
```

An alternative syntax is to use so-called *compound literals* and write
`point_arr[i] = (point) {x, y};`, which is equivalent to the above code.